# Fastest way to Iterate a Matrix with vectors as entries in numpy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm using a function in python's opencv library to get the light flow movement of my hand as I move it around. Specifically http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback

This function outputs a numpy array

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, gray, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
print flow.shape # prints (480,320,2)
```

So flow is a matrix with each entry a vector. I want a way to quantify this matrix so I though of using the L1 Matrix norm (numpy.linalg.norm(flow, 1)) Which throws a improper dimensions to norm error.

I'm thinking about getting around this by calculating the euclidean norm of every vector and then finding the L1 norm of a matrix with the distances of the vectors.

I'm having trouble iterating through the flow matrix efficiently. I have done it using two for loops by going first through columns and then rows, but it's way too slow.

```
            r,c,d = flow.shape 
            flowprime = numpy.zeros((r,c),flow.dtype)
            for i in range(0,r):
                for j in range (0,c):
                    flowprime[i,j] = numpy.linalg.norm(flow[i,j], 2)
            print(numpy.linalg.norm(flowprime, 1))
```

I had also tried using numpy.nditer but

```
for x in numpy.nditer(flow, op_flags=['readwrite']):
   print x
```

just prints a single value rather than a vector.

What would be the fastest way to iterate through a numpy matrix with vectors as entries, norm them and then take the L1 norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of numpy version 1.9, `norm` takes an `axis` argument.

Aside from that, say what you want ideally, and almost surely you can ask `numpy` to do it.  E.g., assuming no complex entries or missing values, the simplest case `np.sqrt((flow**2).sum())` or the case I think you describe `np.linalg.norm(np.sqrt((flow**2).sum(axis=-1)),1)`.

Comment: Hey thanks I'll have to look into the axis=-1 argument later tonight, but other than that it makes sense